# How to post generic objects to a Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create a website that displays a form.
The fields of the form depend on a request parameter (and also the form backing bean).
This is my controller that renders the different forms:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private MyBeanRegistry registry;

    @RequestMapping("/add/{name}")
    public String showForm(@PathVariable String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("bean", registry.lookup(name));

        return "add";
    }

}
```

The corresponding view looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" th:action="@{|/add/${name}|}" th:object="${bean}">
        <th:block th:replace="|${name}::fields|"></th:block>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is an example fragment that displays the form fields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <th:block th:fragment="fields">
        <label for="firstName">First name</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}" /><br />
        <label for="lastName">Last name</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}" />
    </th:block>
</body>
</html>
```

The looked up bean would be like this:

```
public class MyExampleBean {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    // Getters & setters

}
```

The form is rendered correctly, but how can I receive the form back in the controller?
And how can I validate the submitted bean? I tried the following method, but obviously
it can not work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@PathVariable String name, @Valid Object bean) {
    System.out.println(bean);

    return "redirect:/add/" + name;
}
```

Spring creates a new instance of `Object` but the submitted values are lost.
So how can I accomplish this task?

Comment: It looks like a scope problem, is there a parameter to tell you want a session scope for that form ?

Comment: I did not set a scope on the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only wanted to deal with a limited number of beans, you could have one `@RequestMapping` method for each bean, all delegating to a private method that would *do the job*. You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30576659/3545273).

If you want to be able to accept bean dynamically, you will have to do *by hand* what Spring does automagically :

- only use the request and not a model attribute
- find the bean in registry by the `PathVariable` name
- do explicitely the binding

But hopefully Spring offers the subclasses of `WebDataBinder` as helpers :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@PathVariable String name, WebRequest request) {
    //System.out.println(bean);

    Object myBean = registry.lookup(name);
    WebRequestDataBinder binder = new WebRequestDataBinder(myBean);
    // optionnaly configure the binder
    ...
    // trigger actual binding of request parameters
    binder.bind(request);
    // optionally validate
    binder.validate();
    // process binding results
    BindingResult result = binder.getBindingResult();
    ...

    return "redirect:/add/" + name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The second approach works very well, but how can I add validation? I added a validator for my object using `binder.addValidators()`. The validator checks if `firstName` and `lastName` from the above example are empty using `ValidationUtils`. When I submit an empty form and check the `BindingResult` it says that there are no errors.

Comment: I just saw that I have to call `binder.validate()` after the binding.

Answer (score 0):

As for validation i don't know, but for retrieving the values, you could try the below

(WARNING: i didn't try this code, as i couldn't at the time of writing).

Change the `processForm` handler to handle `HttpServletRequest` insead of type `Object`, and get the sumbitted values from the paramters map, example :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add/{name}", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String processForm(@PathVariable String name, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make two changes to your code,

1. Annotate your `TestController` with `@SessionAttributes("bean")` it will keep your model attribute with the name `bean` stored in the session
2. Add `@ModelAttribute("bean")` to your `processForm` method, so `processForm(@PathVariable String name, @Valid @ModelAttribute("bean") Object bean)`. As the model attribute `bean` is registered as session attribute as well it will retrieve it from session, and will keep the values

If your `processForm` method is residing in a different controller, make sure to annotate that controller with `@SessionAttributes("bean")` as well

The following should be an example of the working controller

```
@SessionAttributes("bean")
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private MyBeanRegistry registry;

    @RequestMapping("/add/{name}")
    public String showForm(@PathVariable String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("bean", registry.lookup(name));

        return "add";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@PathVariable String name, @Valid @ModelAttribute("bean") Object bean) {
       System.out.println(bean);
       return "redirect:/add/" + name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Defeats the purpose of building RESTful applications